# Adaptative layout iOS 8 and iOS 7

Tags: ios7, ios8, autolayout, adaptive-layout

I've to develop an app that should work on iOS 7 and iOS 8 devices. I'm using Xcode 6 to develop it and I'm having issue to design the UI. I designed the UI by using the adaptive layout, so when I try to run the app on a device in which it's installed iOS 8 it works great on all display dimension (iPhone 4s, iPhone 5, 5c, 5s and iPhone 6, 6 Plus) as you can see on the following screenshot:

[image]

When I try to run it on a device in which it's installed iOS 7 I get some trouble as you can see on the following screenshot:

[image]

How I can fix that issue? I need to design another Storyboard that the system should use if it detect iOS 7? I hope you can help me

Comment: For the Question : I need to design another storyboard that the system use if detect iOS7 ? NO, as Size classes are backward compatible. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/DeployingSizeClassesonEarlieriOSVersions.html

Comment: Share your project so that we can help you quickly,there must be minor mistake.